# p:autocomplete array null after last itemunselect

Tags: arrays, primefaces, autocomplete

What is happening to the bounded array of a p:autocomplete with multi-selection = true if you "delete" (event "itemunselect") the last item from the autocompletebox.
Is the array set to null or is it only empty?

XML:

```
<p:autoComplete id="mulitAutoTags"
                        value="#{entityHandler.entity.tags}" 
                        completeMethod="#{entityListHandler.completeAreaWithCreation}" 
                        var="_tag"
                        itemLabel="#{_tag.value}"
                        itemValue="#{_tag}"
                        multiple="true"
                        size="300"
                        converter="#{entityConverter}">

              <p:ajax event="itemUnselect" listener="#{entityHandler.startSearch()}" update=":tags" />

            </p:autoComplete>
```

ListHandler:

```
public List<Tag> completeAreaWithCreation(String query) {

List<Tag> returnList = this.entityManager.createNamedQuery(Tag.NAMED_QUERY_GET_TAGS_BY_LIKE, Tag.class).setParameter("tag", query.toLowerCase().trim() + "%").getResultList();

if(returnList.size() == 0){
    if(query.endsWith(" ")){
        entityHandler.create();
        entityHandler.getEntity().value(query.trim());
        entityHandler.save();
    }
    returnList = completeAreaWithCreation(query.trim());
}

return returnList;
```

}

And here is (part) my entity:

```
@Table(name = "WF_TICKET")
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class WorkflowTicket extends Workflow{

....


private List<Tag> tags = new ArrayList<Tag>(0);

....

@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name="WF_TICKET_TAG_L", joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "ID_TICKET", nullable = false, updatable = false)} ,inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name ="ID_TAG", nullable = false, updatable = false) })
    public List<Tag> getTags() {
        return schlagworts;
    }

    public void setTags(List<Tag> tagss) {
        this.tags = tagss;
    }

....

}
```

Now, I click on the last item, which is selected and afterwards I get a nullpointerexception (this.entity.getTags().size()) in my entityHandler, because the arrayList is null and I don't know why.

This is only a short part of the method which is called by teh itemunselect event:

```
@SuppressWarnings("null")
    public void startSearch(){

    ....

            if(this.entity.getTags().size() > 0){

                .....

                }
    }
```

Comment: Where is your xhtml and managed bean code,sir SLtrike ?

Comment: here it comes, but don't know how this should help, it was a general question, what is happening to the array in background. Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Made a solution myself, but I still don't understand why the array is null.

```
@SuppressWarnings("null")
public void startSearch(){

....

    if(this.entity.getTags() == null){
       this.entity.setTags(new ArrayList<Tag>(0));
    }
        if(this.entity.getTags().size() > 0){

            .....

            }
}
```